# Gson parse different Json object class in Nested JsonArray

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, gson

I am writing my first Gson sample. Now I know how to parse basic JsonObject / JsonArray like as below.

Successful JSON sample:

```
   { "name":"A",
      "title":[ {"name":"B"},
                {"name":"C"}]
    }
```

Class code:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Name> title;

    public Person(){
    }

    public String getname(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setname(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public ArrayList<Name> getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(ArrayList<Name> title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}

public class Name{
    private String name;

    public String getname(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setname(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Jave code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Person result = gson.fromJson("JSONString", Person.class);
```

But now I have this Nested Json, I don't know how to distinguish **`private ArrayList <Name>`** in Class Person. **Use JAVA interface?TypeAdapter?**

```
{ "name":"A",
  "title":[ {"name":"B"},
            {"name":"C",
             "title":["name":"a","name":"b"]
            },
            {"name":"D"},
            {"name":"E",
              "title":["name":"a","name":"b"]
            }
          ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON nested array with GSON on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379387/parsing-json-nested-array-with-gson-on-android)